# Pythagorean theorem and Autocad objects

Tags: c#

I've been trying to use that Math.Sqrt method but I'm not getting very far.  Are the ###'s maybe screwing me up?  I'm getting unable to convert errors when trying to call the length/elevation variables using that method.  Should I approach this from a different direction?

Full disclosure: newbie.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    AcDb.ObjectId id = AcDb.ObjectId.Null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void GetVertices()
    {
        AcAp.Document doc = AcAp.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        AcDb.Database db = doc.Database;
        AcEd.Editor ed = doc.Editor;

        using (var doclock = doc.LockDocument())
        {
            using (var trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                var options = new AcEd.PromptEntityOptions("\nSelect a Line:");
                options.SetRejectMessage("That is not Line" + "\n");
                options.AddAllowedClass(typeof(AcDb.Line), true);
                var result = ed.GetEntity(options);

                if (result.Status != AcEd.PromptStatus.OK)
                    return;
                this.id = result.ObjectId;
                var line = (AcDb.Line)trans.GetObject(this.id, AcDb.OpenMode.ForRead);
                var vertexClass = AcTrx.RXClass.GetClass(typeof(AcDb.Line));


                var length = line.Length.ToString("#.##");
                tbLength.Text = length;

                var northing = line.EndPoint.Y.ToString("#.##");
                tbNorthing.Text = northing;

                var easting = line.EndPoint.X.ToString("#.##");
                tbEasting.Text = easting;

                var elevation = line.EndPoint.Z.ToString("#.##");
                tbElevation.Text = elevation;

                var endpoint = line.EndPoint.ToString();
                tbEndpoint.Text = endpoint;

                var slope = Math.Sqrt(elevation/length)  //something something something
            }
        }
    }

    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        GetVertices();
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What's the expected result? Please also ensure that you post valid example code.

Comment: Post the FULL errors you are getting and indicate where in your code they are happening.

Comment: I don't know what code to write to get slope.

Comment: What code have you tried? Why didn't it work? Did you get errors? Post them. The code you've posted won't even compile. Please put more effort into your question if you want people to help.

Comment: Edited sample code, again I don't know what I need to do to get the actual slope.

Comment: By the way, I don't see any relation to the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elevation` and `length` are strings. You cannot perform math on strings!

Try

```
double slope = Math.Sqrt(line.EndPoint.Z / line.Length);
```

Or change your code to:

```
double length = line.Length
tbLength.Text = length.ToString("#.##");

double northing = line.EndPoint.Y;
tbNorthing.Text = northing.ToString("#.##");

double easting = line.EndPoint.X;
tbEasting.Text = easting.ToString("#.##");

double elevation = line.EndPoint.Z;
tbElevation.Text = elevation.ToString("#.##");

double endpoint = line.EndPoint;
tbEndpoint.Text = endpoint.ToString();

double slope = Math.Sqrt(elevation/length);
```

And also I suggest you to use `var` only when it represents a real simplification and the type can easily be inferred or if the exact type is not of great interest as for LINQ query results with complicated `IGouping<whatever>` constructs possibly involving anonymous types.

```
var x = new Dictionary<string, List<Entity<Person>>>();
```

.... is a simplyfication and yet the type is visible as you can read it on the same line;

```
var i = 15;
```

is not a simplyfication over

```
int i = 15;
```

I would never use `var` as substitution for simple types like `int`, `string`, `double` etc.

Comment: But it would make me so happy.

Comment: "But it would make me so happy" - wishes versus reality usually lose; anyways, how'd you want to mathematically add a tome of Shakespeare to a tome of Bible? :)